# Replication error masked by sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown returning 'String or binary data would be truncated'

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

One of our replication jobs is failing on step 3, which runs *sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown*, returns a *'String or binary data would be truncated'*. Which of course led us down the path of trying to find a problem in the databases. However we compared the two databases and they are identical. From what I can tell the error is actually a bug in *sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown*.

Eventually I checked the job again and step 2 was also failing and throwing a mini dump. When we looked at the dump it says:

> the thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access

The id running the job is a SQL Id that is sysadmin, the step (2) is running under the agent service account. The service account has access to the snapshot directory. We have multiple other replication jobs using the same security setup that are working fine.

SQL Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4532097) - 13.0.5102.14 (X64)
> Dec 31 2019 22:39:35
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Anyone have any idea where I can find the permissions error? Or steps I can use to start narrowing it down?

Comment: The truncation error is a bug and I'm reporting it to MS but the rest of it isn't as far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you mean? The error "the thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access" is an unhandled exception that produces a dump and the application crashes. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Ahh ok. I thought you meant the truncation error which also appears to be a bug. I guess I'll report them both and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MS releases a patch (not sure if will ever do), this is a quick fix:

1. Get and save the source code of this procedure

   `[distribution].[sys].[sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown]`
2. Edit the source and find the variable @message, change its length to 4000. Then find the column message in the temp table #JobHistory and do the same
3. Start SQL Server in Single mode from CMD in Administrative mode

   `path_to_binary\sqlservr.exe -m"SQLCMD"`
4. Open another console window and start sqlcmd to connect to the instance

   `sqlcmd -S . -U sa -P`
5. Put the catalog in read-write

   `USE mssqlsystemresource`
   `GO`

   `alter database mssqlsystemresource set read_write`
   `GO`
6. Paste the code modified.
7. Restore the catalog to read_only mode

   `alter database mssqlsystemresource set read_only`
   `GO`
8. Shutdown the single mode instance

   `SHUTDOWN`

   `GO`
9. Start the instance using the service console as usual

Comment: Where shoud you paste the code modified. I just get this error when pasting it in the second CMD window: Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 7]
Invalid object name 'sys.sp_MSdetect_nonlogged_shutdown'.

Comment: @Torgeir which version are you using?